# French character user input and display

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, special-characters

I have an html form where users can enter their name. Some of my users will be French and will have to use characters like é for example. I then fetch the information and display it for confirmation on the next page, the problem is that all these characters are being displayed as question marks.

I know how to use html entities and I represent all the french characters I use on the website like this, é becomes `& eacute;` (w/out the space) and so on. I`m not using a database or anything like that so PHP is of no use to me.

I found this function from here [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/)

```
function htmlEncode(value){
    return String(value).replace(/é/g, '&eacute;').replace(/É/g,'&Eacute;').replace(/È/g, '&Egrave;').replace(/è/g, '&egrave;');
}
```

The problem is when I inspect the source of my webpage it shows the accented characters in the function as black question marks. My meta tags are always declared properly and I tried `<meta charset="UTF-8">` as well as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` but still no luck. So I guess my question here is, how can I convert accented characters from a user's input into html entities using Javascript?

Comment: Is the problem just when inspecting the source code, or does the function actually not work?

Comment: It doesn't work, so when I inspected the source it showed black question marks so I'm thinking it can't even look for these characters since it's not recognizable in the function itself.